Shadows disappear when I stop moving camera or render in Eevee
I'm having an issue with the shadows in Eevee. All shadows appear really soft and not dark at all. (see pictures below) I've looked around on forums and haven't found anything that works yet.



Not sure if the images work but in case they don't here is and alternative link:
https://imgur.com/a/diXHjtu

When you move a camera shadow is roughly calculated to keep it in real time feedback. When you release camera movement shadow is calculated precisely into final as setuped. So result is adequate to your setup that we don't see.For more info share (blend-exchange.com) your simplified blend, delete all keep just all light sources or anything that participate on such soft result of shadow.
